# How to shift frequency with sine signal?

Tags: gnuradio, frequency, usrp

`cosine` signal can make `square` signal shift frequency.

[image: squar_,ove.png]

[image: suare_resul.png]
If I have only `sine` signal source,how to make `square` signal shift frequency?

Comment: You need to understand real signal versus complex spectrum. Complex multiplication of a (complex; I and Q components) input signal with Sine/Cosine as shift frequency results in a complex output signal. The problem is the generation of a square wave as complex signal: limited spectrum. Wait for a better explanation.

Comment: Note that a sine wave has no harmonics; a square wave has an infinite number of harmonics.

Comment: Aside from this still being a math, not a radio question: There's absolutely no difference between a cosine and a sine; one is just the other, delayed by ¼ period. It's absolutely not clear where this question comes from, because you – still, after much asking in your last Q's comments– did not add any of your own math to this question. And we're really not here to do your part of the homework that says "write down what a frequency shift is". Doing this minimal part on your own would either directly answer your question, or if it's hard, give you a sensible question to ask.

Comment: For those interested in discussing the close-voteyness I have on this: We have a meta question *exactly* on this: https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/466/4076

Comment: @MarcusMüller,Thanks for the reference link.I asked a radio question related to gnuradio.Maybe you have answer,please post it,even math methodology behind it.

Comment: For the third time: Again, I don't know where to start explaining if **you** don't edit your question and add **your** definition of what it means to shift a signal in frequency, and explain in detail why you can't apply that here! (and this being about GNU Radio doesn't make it about "amateur radio or radio in general".)

Comment: also, I already posted basically an answer in my first comment to your quesiton.